# Filter events with multiple allowed topic values

Tags: web3j

I'm building a contract listener. I am only interested in 1 particular contract, let's say at address `0x123...789`.

`final EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, null, "0x123...789")`

All events emitted by this contract have 1 thing in common: `address indexed` as their first parameter. Number of parameters (and topics) varies, but they all have the same first parameter.

I want to create a filter, which will only accept events where that `address` value is contained in a list that I define:

`acceptedAddresses.contains(event.getTopics(1)) == true`

My current setup is as follows:

```
filter.addOptionalTopics(acceptedAddresses.toArray(new String[0]));
this.web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(MyEventPRocessor::process)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't receive any events, despite addresses matching the topic.

How can I achieve this?

---

As a side note, I have seen 2 implementations of `EthFilter#addOptionalTopics`:

1. Use varargs to define a single value which is required in the event, with vararg index being equivalent to `topic position - 1`

```
// Filter events where topic1 == 1, and apply no filters to topic2 and topic3
ethFilter.addOptionalTopics(1, null, null)
```

2. Use multiple calls to `EthFilter#addOptionalTopics`, where each call defines a set of accepted values for the current topic in line:

```
ethFilter.addOptionalTopics(1, 2, 3) // Filter events where List.of(1,2,3).contains(topic1)
ethFilter.addOptionalTopics(null)    // Do not filter topic2
ethFilter.addOptionalTopics(4,5,6) // Filter events where List.of(4,5,6).contains(topic3)
```